# Deliver mails in Maildir in /var/spool/mail with Postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, maildir

I search for hours without finding the solution and it drives me crazy.

Is it possible to ensure, without using Procmail, that Postfix delivers emails in the form of Maildir `{cur,new,tmp}` in
`/var/spool/mail/$USER`? How?

I have `mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail` but it throws me away since it wants to create a mailbox there, and it finds a directory there:

`(cannot update mailbox /var/spool/mail/regine for user regine. cannot open file: Is a directory)`

If I add `home_mailbox = ./` or `home_mailbox = /`, mails are delivered in Maildir format, but in `/home/regine/{cur,new,tmp}`.

How can I have this same Maildir format in `/var/spool/mail/USER/`?

Postfix's configuration:

```
# postconf -n
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = ./
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
luser_relay = postmaster@domain.fr
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailbox_size_limit = 204800000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maximal_queue_lifetime = 30d
message_size_limit = 102400000
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = domain.fr
myhostname = vps1.domain.fr
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_maps
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydomain domain.com
relay_recipient_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients regexp:/etc/postfix/relay_recipients-regexp
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix/${mail_version}
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain reject_unauth_destination reject_unauth_pipelining reject_rbl_client noptr.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client spam.spamrats.com reject_rbl_client dyna.spamrats.com
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/vps1.domain.fr/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/vps1.domain.fr/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Can you please show Postfix configuration (as per [tag description](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postfix))? Important bit here is, are your users local system users, or do you use some other database for recipients? The `local` delivery agent (whose configuration parameter this is) supports **either** UNIX-style mailbox (a single file named after the user) within `mail_spool_directory` or in user's home directory, **or** Maildir-style mailbox *in users's home directory, `/home/username`*.

Comment: Only local users (for the moment).
I'll edit my post to add postconf -n

Comment: If I read you correctly, impossible to get Maildir-style mailbox in mail_spool_directory ?
Only solution is to use procmail ?

Comment: ... or using other delivery agent that `local`; if you plan to expand your mail server (e.g. use virtual domains and so on), consider using `virtual` delivery agent for all real "human" (I mean, non-local-system-related entities). It supports setting `virtual_mailbox_base` to whatever format so it can deliver in a structure like you want.

Comment: That will require changing `mydomain` to be not the domain where users belong, and adding the actual user domain  into `virtual_mailbox_domains`. Also you'll be needing to set a proper `virtual_mailbox_maps`. Though I never tried to use it with a system-local users. YMMV. [Read the docs](https://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html); this might be a gross change, but it might be worth doing now while small, depending on your later plans with this server.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think it will be easier to use procmail.

Comment: The `/var/spool/mail/$USER` is a traditional location for mbox format user's inbox. It is not really a path for Maildir delivery. What's wrong with the standard `~/Maildir/`? All the mail server software will be able to use it out-of-the-box.

Comment: @EsaJokinen In fact, I've always done it like that, out of habit, but also for certain technical reasons. It was more comfortable for me in my use. But it was always with Procmail.
I think that on this server, the best thing is probably to go back to something more usual. Thank you for making it happen for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want postfix to use Maildirs, you have to add a slash to the end of the mail_spool_directory configuration value. Otherwise it will use mbox-style delivery.

So, in your case you would need to change the value of mail_spool_directory to `mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail/`.

.